# Are there any mathematics based game apps which require students (between 10 - 16 years) to apply their maths knowledge to play the game

Tags: secondary-education, number-theory, mathematics-in-daily-life, recreational-learning, rational-numbers

So, what we essentially mean is students will apply their knowledge on divisibility, factorization, prime numbers, lcm, gcf, decimals, fractions, etc to play the game. A somewhat different approach to practice maths and to help them through with these concepts.
Depending on age there will be advanced levels with more other topics involved in designing the game.

Are there any such game app?

Comment: There are many fraction games, e.g., [this one](https://www.nctm.org/Classroom-Resources/Illuminations/Interactives/Fraction-Game/) from the *National Council of Teachers of Mathematics* in the U.S.

Comment: I do not know of any but i would love to work on some. Adding to your list of concepts that could be gamified: slope, intersect, cartesian coordinates

Comment: How about https://projecteuler.net/ ?

Comment: I also remember there was a game like the Worms shooting cannons game, but where instead of adjusting the angles and powers of the cannons, you could program the cannons by writing an y = something(x) equation so that the cannonball would follow the corresponding trajectory. I can't remember the name of that game though.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not quite an app, I believe it fits within the spirit of the question: Desmos activities.

https://teacher.desmos.com/collections/featured

While some Desmos activities are very math-forward, others follow Dan Myers' "Three Acts" format, [giving students an interesting scenario and asking them to solve it with math,](https://teacher.desmos.com/activitybuilder/custom/57e04d6fc8c899190bdbb450?collections=5d9d12cd9bb4713ab3b0d267) and showing the students what their computations give them in real time. Others ask students to get [marbles to slide through certain points](https://teacher.desmos.com/activitybuilder/custom/566b317b4e38e1e21a10aafb?collections=5da6462c8b305273be677729). Many are teacher-paced, but most can be student-paced, and all can be modified by instructors.

One other (probably popular) answer that I do not yet see is the [Dragonbox](https://dragonbox.com/) series. In particular, algebra 12+ and Elements give puzzles that rely on algebra and on geometry to solve!